# ER Diagram design issues

Tags: entity-relationship

I'm designing an ER diagram for a social network and recently I got involved in an argument with my colleagues whether this part is right or wrong

[ER DIAGRAM PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nBZp.png)

Where **Faqet**(Pages) is connected with **Shfrytezuesi**(User) using **three** actions, *pelqen* is for storing likes, *krijon faqe* to know who created the page, and *udheheq* to store all page admins, so my question is

*is this design wrong?*

Can two tables be linked with more than one action, this is where I'm not certain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to have any number of relationships between any number of entity sets. My only concern with the diagram is that multiple role lines below `Shfrytezuesi` are merged into one - I recommend keeping them distinct.

Note that in the entity-relationship model, we don't link tables. That idea comes from the old network data model, in which rows represented entities, tables represented entity sets, and links between rows/tables represented relationships.

One disadvantage with that model is that it supports only directed binary relationships - many-to-many binary, ternary and higher relationships and relationships with attributes all required associative entities to be introduced. However, three binary relationships aren't equivalent to a ternary relationship, and not all relationships can be represented in binary data models.

The ER model supports n-ary relationships and attributes on relationships. Entity sets are represented by their primary keys and relationships by combinations of entity keys. Entity sets plus attributes form entity relations, relationship sets plus attributes form entity relations. These relations get mapped to tables. In practice, tables with the same primary keys get combined to reduce the number of tables, which means one-to-one and one-to-many relationships get combined into the relations for one of their associated entity sets.

Regardless of how tables are combined, attributes and relationships are represented by sets of columns. For example, based on your diagram, `Pelqen` would be represented as `(FID PK, SID)` (assuming `SID` is the primary key of `Shfrytezuesi`). These columns might have different names, e.g. `SID` might be renamed to `AdminSID`, especially if the relationship was combined into `Faqet`. The old network data model would view `FID FK -> FID PK` as a relationship, which as described above and below is a very limited kind of relationship and not the approach taken by the ER model.

Another disadvantage of the network data model is predetermined access paths, which means we have to navigate from table to table using the predefined relationships. This complicated queries and data processing significantly. This limitation was one of the main drivers for the development of the relational model, to which the ER model maps. The understanding of tables as relations in the RM enables us to construct and navigate arbitrary access paths using joins. So, we do link tables in the RM, but at query time and as needed rather than at design time. The ER model is used for conceptual design only and doesn't describe relationships between tables, only relationships between entity sets.

Now, the ER model isn't a complete and consistent logical model like the RM, but it is a significant improvement over the network data model. An even more rigorous approach than ER would be object-role modeling, but that's a different topic.

Comment: @reeanb Thank you reaanb for the advice, I have now divided the lines, but the last part I didn't understand, what do you mean by "we don't link tables", you mean directly? please explain thank you in advance

Comment: @BleronQorri I expanded on my statement, I hope it helps.

Comment: @reeanb It did, I followed your advice and seperated the lines and my ER model was correct, thank you